# How to process a CSV file with a number of columns changing in SSIS?

Tags: sql-server-2005, ssis

I have a complete CSV file that for instance have 6 columns:

```
Rec ID | Charge Category | Charge Type Category | Product Name | Account No | Cost
```

I've been running SSIS no problem with this condition.

However, we found that one of the CSV file that is using less column than we have for instance:

```
Rec ID | Charge Type Category | Product Name |Cost
```

How do we handle this cause using "Flat File Connection Manager" type of connection is not working ?!?!

Any other approach that we need to explore?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

If you only have those two cases, you can create three file connections. Use the first one to read the whole line and process just the header. Count the number of columns in it and create two parallel flows - one for "short" format, one for "long", where each of those use a different connection definition.

A bit more complicated option would be to do all this in a Script Transformation in the data flow. Let your CSV file read a file line by line and pass it to the Script, which parses the line and assigns the existing column values to a subset of all the possible outputs defined. Outputs should be defined in such a way that all the possible columns are configured (similar to this: [SSIS split string](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13085783/ssis-split-string/13090189#13090189))

The main parts of the solution are:

1. Flat file connection which reads the file line by line (set the field delimiter to a non existent combination of for example #$#) and
2. Scipt Task in the transformation mode with having a single input (FullLine) and all the possible outputs defined:

   [image]

In the script, you can use concepts beautifully described here: http://dwbi1.wordpress.com/2011/02/27/ssis-importing-files-read-the-first-n-rows/

After writing all this, I've just realised that the Script Task Source would probably be the easiest way to do it, with the same idea of defining all the possible columns as output.

Comment: Unfortunately, we need to handle the variance of the number of columns. Does this mean that we need to do in Script Task then?

Comment: Answer expanded with the second paragraph.

Comment: Are you referring this as Script Component but then you choose the Transformation option right? Isn't that you need to point to a file which is that what we are having an issue ... remember it's a dynamic number of columns (in CSV).

Comment: Answer edited with illustration added and a link to a document that has very similar example.