# SSIS split string

Tags: string, parsing, ssis, etl

I have a dataset (log file) with a number of columns; one of them is `Other-Data` (see below) which is an unordered string and need to parse it to create new columns according the `u` value (U1, U2, U3, etc...)

```
OTHER-DATA
u1=EUR;u2=sss:Checkout-Step4:Orderacknowledgement;u3=DE:de:hom;u11=1;u12=302338533;u13=SVE1511C5E;u14=575.67
```

Can anyone help with this?

Answer (score 0):

One way would be to add a script transformation component, use the OTHER-DATA as your input row, parse it with C# or VB.Net and output it in the synchronous mode into the predefined outputs. This will only work if you can prepare outputs U1 to Un in advance. The very similar problem is explained here: http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/193855/An-indespensible-SSIS-transformation-component-Scr